# How to properly import Apache HttpClient in NetBeans?

Tags: java, http, import, client

I'm a newbie in Java and I'm trying to import and use the Http library found at [Apache HttpClient Library (HttpClient 4.1.2)](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

I've downloaded both sources and binary (with .jar files) files and now I'm stuck at what to do.

First thing I did was:
    **select project in Netbeans > right click "Properties" > select Libraries > Add Jar/Folder > select .jar files**

This process create a folder called **libraries** in the root of my project and import the .jar files into. However when using `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` in my projects it shows **Cannot find symbol** (about HttpClient) with `import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.*;`

But reading on [Managing Source and Class Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html) is it good if I can manually organize httpclient library in my project root folder so that it looks like `<projet root folder>\org\apache\http\client\HttpClient` and so on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jar files are different than source and class files, you don't need to organize them hierarchically like you would with .java and .class files, because the contents of the jar file are already organized that way.

I assume that you're using an ant project in netbeans. In that case the library node in your project doesn't really correspond to a folder on the disk (unlike the sources node). The most convenient thing to do is to create a lib directory under your project root, and then put your jar files in there. After that, then add them to your project. This way, netbeans will refer to them via a relative path to the jar files, which means you can now copy the entire project somewhere else (perhaps through source control) and the jar references will still be correct.

The downside of this is some duplication of jars, but that's not that big of a deal. You also have to manage the dependencies by hand, which can be a chore. The upside of this (in netbeans at least) is that the ant projects work really well in netbeans, the maven type projects are newer and not quite as well supported. I also find that ant projects build faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got problem in your `import` statement:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.*;
```

I think that should be either

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
```

or

```
import org.apache.http.client.*;
```

Why would you want to manage an external library like that. You have already thrown the library in the class path and that's enough right?